# How To Handle A Long Internet Disconnection In Background Using Twilio In iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, voip

I am developing an iOS VoIP app using Twilio. I need the app to keep listening for incoming connections at all times.

When app is in background, the Twilio library handles keeping the app running. When a disconnection from Twilio happens (due to an expired capability token for example), a delegate method `TCDevice:didStopListeningForIncomingConnections` is called, and from there I am able to re-establish connection to Twilio. **But if the disconnection occurs due to no internet availability**, this method will be called when there is no internet connection, and I will not be able to establish the connection such that even if the user reconnected later, I cannot re-establish the connection.

So the Question is: **How To Re-establish Connection To Twilio After A Long Internet Disconnection?**

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?